# How to mount a whole disk image formatted in UFS filesystem

Tags: mount, dd

I am trying to mount a raw disk image created by `dd` command from whole one disk. My disk has a UFS file system on its drives. `mount` command needs a special drive to mount. How can I do it?

Comment: The entire disk, or just a partition?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

---

*My command trys to mount the image as read/write, however you should read this before using it: [Mounting ufs partition with read/write permissions on ubuntu](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24589/mounting-ufs-partition-with-read-write-permissions-on-ubuntu-10-04)*

---

First assign your image to a loop device:

```
$ sudo losetup -f $HOME/path/to/disk.img
```

You might want to use `-P` option as suggested in comments too.

Find in which path your image has been assigned:

```
$ sudo losetup -j $HOME/path/to/disk.img
/dev/loop0: [xxxx]: (/home/path/to/disk.img)
```

So it's on `loop0`.

Check and see if `ufs` module is loaded:

```
$ lsmod | grep ufs
```

If it's not, load it using:

```
$ sudo modprobe ufs
```

Then mount your partitions like:

```
$ sudo mount -t ufs /dev/loop0p1 /mnt
```

You might need to mount it with `-o ufstype=ufs2`:

```
$ sudo mount -t ufs -o ufstype=ufs2 /dev/loop0p1 /mnt
```

---

The device is:

```
/dev/loop0
```

And partitions are:

```
/dev/loop0p1
/dev/loop0p2
...
```

Comment: The module will be loaded automatically if needed.

Comment: @psusi I wasn't sure about it and not able to test it so I decide to load it manually, thanks :)

Comment: Did `losetup` automatically create the partition loops (loop0p1 & p2) itself, no `-P` required?

Comment: @Xen2050 I had to use -P option to be able to get my partions to show up (without the -P option the partitions did not show up.) Thanks for hinting this out! :)